# Pergunta sem Relacionado

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Percebi que [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330924/75104) não possui os links de perguntas relacionadas.

[image: Sem Relacionado]

**Seria um bug? Ou algumas perguntas não possuem mesmo.** (Pois é a primeira vez que vi isso no SOpt ou SOen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obrigado pelo feedback!

Isto é um comportamento normal. No Stack Overflow em português há cerca de 400 perguntas sem "relacionadas."

---

Thank you for the feedback!

It's normal behaviour. We figured out that on Stack Overflow in Portuguese there are about 400 questions with no related ones.